# Right way to tell CMake to "use same dependency as a dependent package"?

Tags: cmake, package, dependency-management, idioms

Suppose you have 3 software packages: A, B and C. A depends on B and on C, B depends on C. Also, A and B are configured using CMake, but exist independently of each other, i.e. B is not a subproject of A, isn't in some subdirectory, doesn't rely on A's files etc.

Now, in my CMakeLists.txt for A, I want to tell CMake "try to use the same version of package C that B is using" (either with some fallback or without).

I know one way to do this is to parse the `CMakeCache.txt` of B using shell tools, but I'm hoping there's a nicer, higher-level idiom for doing this.

Comment: Have you looked at [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)?

Comment: @legalize: I have now. But - that seems to assume the main package has its own definition of the dependency on foobar, and does not obtain it from the external project's build files.

Comment: I think the best advice these days is to use Conan or vcpkg to orchestrate your builds. Not a full answer to your question, thus a comment.

Comment: @AlexReinking: But the CMakeLists.txt needs to specify its requirements, still.

Comment: Yes, via `find_package`. Conan and vcpkg set CMake variables to direct `find_package` to a consistent set of dependencies.

Comment: @AlexReinking; Ok, but I still need to express what's in this question's title via the `find_package()`. Either that, or the `find_package()` for B also finds-package C and exposes it to me.